# How do I match an exact string with special characters in it?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
import re 
data = "sda      8:0    0 107374182400  0 disk \r\n\root@awx1:~[root@awx1 ~]# s"
re.sub(r"root@awx1:~\[root@awx1 ~\]# s","",data)
'sda      8:0    0 107374182400  0 disk \r\n\root@awx1:~[root@awx1 ~]# s'
```

It does not gets replaced. How can I match the substring with regex and replace it?

Comment: Note: `awx1 != qa-dc1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what [`re.escape`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.escape) is for.

```
>>> data = "sda      8:0    0 107374182400  0 disk \r\nroot@awx1:~[root@awx ~]# s"
>>> substring = re.escape(                            "root@awx1:~[root@awx ~]# s")
>>> re.sub(substring, '', data)
'sda      8:0    0 107374182400  0 disk \r\n'
```

Note: I removed an extra `\` character from your example that I don't think was really there.  Between the `\r\n` and the `root`.